# Is there any way how to ensure basic authentication for REST services deployed in latest wso2ei 6.4.0?

Tags: api, wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to use WSO2EI 6.4.0 as a proxy for SOAP and REST services authentication platform (later maybe authorization).
I found solution in documentation of wso2 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Applying+Security+to+an+API), but unfortunately it is not working.

Adding "handler" element into service definition

```
<handlers>
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

results into exception in design time (eclipse):

```
Invalid mediator <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>    1d6bbce1-08e3-42d5-b550-6a4e224b0028.xml    /.tmp/.org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb line 15 org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.synapseerror
```

Ignoring and deploying such API, makes the API stop working.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: May be that will help https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Basic+Auth. Not really sure what you are trying to archive. Some complicated auth and routing proxy service?

Comment: The way you are trying to add the Basic authentication for API in WSO2EI 6.4.0 is correct. Did you try to add the handler using the source view of the Developer Studio? If so, can you check how it looks like in source view and add it hear to check how it looks like?

Comment: Thak you for the commet simar, but I want to stay simple (not using API manager).

Comment: Yes, I tried it that way Rans, actually this was the only way for me. As you can see in my question, the problem was in design time (eclipse). Sorry I can not attach the picture of it - some policies on stackoverflow do not allow me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to add the Basic authentication for API in WSO2EI 6.4.0 is correct. Developer studio will give a warning as you mentioned, but it should not be an issue. Developer studio will allow setting the handler regardless of the warning and you should be able to create a Composite Application which includes the API and deploy it to ESB. Following is a sample API with the RESTBasicAuthHandler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/testapi" name="testapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" protocol="https" url-mapping="/*">
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint name="testapi_EP">
                    <http uri-template="http://localhost:8080/testapi"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

Comment: Correct, it is working now. Thank you for the support. The warning is very confusing though.